# Bootstrap responsive embed video takes up the whole width and height of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to embed a video into bootstrap website.

But when I do, it takes up the whole width and height of the screen. I want it to be 560px x 315px on desktops and it should be responsive when the desktop size goes below 560px.

I have used:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 div_style">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to customize `div` tag by adding `div_style` class `max-width: 560px;` and `max-height:315px;`, It changes video width to 560px but the height takes up the whole page height.

Comment: Try to add **!important**, max-width: 560px !important; max-height: 315px !important. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please share whole html file ,,, big chunk of code? Maybe something is wrong on other part.

Answer (score 7):

You missed to add `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2`. Something like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 padding-zero embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <div id="foxnews">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KFGbHBbXG_g?modestbranding=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap `embed-responsive` classes use `padding-bottom` to set the "height" of the element.

You can change this property along with `width` within a media query for your desired effect.

```css
@media all and ( min-width: 560px ) {
    .div_style { 
        width:560px;
        padding-bottom:315px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 div_style">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should work in OP's specific case, but it would cause issues if the video was being placed in a col- less than 560px wide.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div className="overlay"></div>

  <div className='container-fluid vids col-md'>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 padding-zero embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <video  playsInline="playsinline" autoPlay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="videos/design.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
  </div>
```